# How to set thumb images for facebook post while i put my website URL

Tags: php, html, facebook, image, codeigniter

When i paste my website link in facebook post box - it automatically detects the meta tag description and display some thumb images . but i need to show only my website logo.check this link

```
http://testing1.buyjapon.com/images/ima_1.PNG
```

Comment: Are we supposed to know how facebook scrapes data? Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it in `<head>` as a `<meta>` property.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/logo.jpg" />
```

from...

**Section 3. Use proper Open Graph tags**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/

Comment: Hi diggersworld, actually my problem is facebook post box while you copy some website url and you paste in the box it automatically took meta description and some images but i have to show my website logo.I tried your above code could not working.please advise me.I'm looking forward you

Comment: Did you have the above code on the page that you were posting the link to on Facebook? Also, did you change the content to be your logo?

Comment: when i post my link in facebook , it automatically detects the images, title and description . i tried using  the code u gave .i doesn't work . kindly give me a solution . Is this possible ?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page you're attempting to share on Facebook?

Comment: Hi diggersworld, this is my link http://linkdrag.osiztechnologies.com/. can you kindly check in your wallpage also check it view source of my web page.I'm looking forward you

Comment: Your image is too small. Needs to be 200x200 or bigger. You can debug graph tags in your page here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug